# Shell script regex to check for a string

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to write a simple regex in a shell script and I can't get it to match anything. I'm not sure if my regex is incorrect or my shell code is incorrect

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# This hook verifies that the commit message contains a reference to a tfs item

# Regex to validate a string contains "#" and 4 or 5 digits
regex="/#\d{4,5}/"
param=$1
echo "param = $param"
echo "regex = $regex"

if [[ $param =~ $regex ]]; then
  output="yes"
else
  output="no"
fi

echo "output = $output"

...
```

I'm running my script with `$ ./myscript "#1234"` and `$ ./myscript "asdf #1234 asdf"` and those should both output "yes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
regex="/#\d{4,5}/"
```

Is not correct regex for BASH. You can use:

```
regex="#[0-9]{4,5}"
```

- No regex delimiters in BASH regex
- `\d`, `\w` properties are not supported

Comment: This doesn't quite work. It also also passes with `$ ./myscript "asdf "#123456789"`...which means my regex is not quite right.

Comment: You need to add a `$` at the end to anchor the match if that's what you want.  A regex will match anywhere in a longer string unless you anchor it.

Comment: @tripleee if I add a `$` at the end that makes it so `$ ./myscript "asdf #1234 asdf"` doesn't work. I basically want to allow a hashtag followed by 4 or 5 digits anywhere in the string.

Comment: So it can be followed by anything as long as it's not a number?  Then `"#[0-9]{4,5}($|[^0-9])"`

Comment: It could be followed by a number again. So this would be allowed `asdf #1234 1` also. I just want to require that hashtag followed by 4 or 5 digits exists anywhere in the string.

Comment: I mean as long as the immediately following character is not a number, or you see the end of the string.  That's what the previous comment does.

Comment: @Catfish: You can use word boundary: `regex="#[0-9]{4,5}\>"`

Comment: @anubhava with your suggestion `asdf #12345 5` fails but it should succeed. @tripleee your suggestion does work

Comment: You need to use single quotes around the regex to have literal backslashes in it, or double the backslash to escape it properly.  I would go with the former, since there are many other metacharacters which could bite you in the behind if you stay with double quotes.

Comment: `regex="#[0-9]{4,5}\>"` works for me on Linux. [See this demo](http://ideone.com/ysNcQ9)